# How to pass form values to new window?

Tags: extjs

I have a form that needs to be printed in a new window. I could get to pass the innerHTML of the form but it seems to not get the values. Here is a sample code:

```
print: function(){
var formPanel = Ext.getCmp('formPanelId');
var formValues = formPanel.getValues(); //this has data but it does not load on the new Window
var myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
myWindow.document.write('<title>' + 'Title' + '</title>');
myWindow.document.write('<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" />');
myWindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/bootstrap.js"></script>');
myWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
myWindow.document.write(formPanel.body.dom.innerHTML);
myWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
}
```

How do I pass the formValues to the new window? I appreciate any advice on this. Thank you!

Comment: Are you creating some iframe ?

Comment: No. I'm not creating an iframe.

Comment: Can you create some sample fiddle not able to get basic issue.Is it new window or extjs window ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass these values to Ext.window.Window you can simple do this while creating the Ext window as follow

```
print: function(){ 
 var formPanel = Ext.getCmp('formPanelId');
 var formValues = formPanel.getValues();
 var myWindow = Ext.create('YourWinodw', {formPanelValues:formValues}); // now in myWindow there is property formPanelValues that hold that value
}
```

If you are using the plain window.document.write as you are doing above you need to immediatly write the values as follow

```
myWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
myWindow.document.write('<title>' + formValues['fieldName'] + '</title>');
```

Comment: He is doing window.open and not creating sencha's window.